# Android Map integration exception

Tags: android, google-maps

i am new on android and i have tried to integrate the google maps with my application , i tried vogella and androidhive also and seen the questions and answers on the stack overflow but nothing works here is the android code

```
    private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10; //10 metters

    //The minimum time beetwen updates in milliseconds
    private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1; // 1 minute
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.mainscreen);
    // .findFragmentById(R.id.map))
    map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

        if (map!=null){
          Marker hamburg = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(HAMBURG)
              .title("Hamburg"));
          Marker kiel = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
              .position(KIEL)
              .title("Kiel")
              .snippet("Kiel is cool")
              .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                  .fromResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher)));
        }

}
```

Here is the xml code

```
<fragment 
android:id="@+id/map"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

And here i have the exceptions please tell me where i am wrong

```
01-21 23:26:47.304: E/AndroidRuntime(1456): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-21 23:26:47.304: E/AndroidRuntime(1456): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.geekdev.animalpark/com.geekdev.animalpark.MainScreen}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #54: Error inflating class fragment
01-21 23:26:47.304: E/AndroidRuntime(1456):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
01-21 23:26:47.304: E/AndroidRuntime(1456):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
01-21 23:26:47.304: E/AndroidRuntime(1456):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
01-21 23:26:47.304: E/AndroidRuntime(1456):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
01-21 23:26:47.304: E/AndroidRuntime(1456):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-21 23:26:47.304: E/AndroidRuntime(1456):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-21 23:26:47.304: E/AndroidRuntime(1456):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
01-21 23:26:47.304: E/AndroidRuntime(1456):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-21 23:26:47.304: E/AndroidRuntime(1456):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-21 23:26:47.304: E/AndroidRuntime(1456):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
01-21 23:26:47.304: E/AndroidRuntime(1456):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
01-21 23:26:47.304: E/AndroidRuntime(1456):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-21 23:26:47.304: E/AndroidRuntime(1456): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #54: Error inflating class fragment
01-21 23:26:47.304: E/AndroidRuntime(1456):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
01-21 23:26:47.304: E/AndroidRuntime(1456):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
01-21 23:26:47.304: E/AndroidRuntime(1456):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
01-21 23:26:47.304: E/AndroidRuntime(1456):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
01-21 23:26:47.304: E/AndroidRuntime(1456):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
01-21 23:26:47.304: E/AndroidRuntime(1456):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
01-21 23:26:47.304: E/AndroidRuntime(1456):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:270)
01-21 23:26:47.304: E/AndroidRuntime(1456):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881)
01-21 23:26:47.304: E/AndroidRuntime(1456):     at com.geekdev.animalpark.MainScreen.onCreate(MainScreen.java:57)
01-21 23:26:47.304: E/AndroidRuntime(1456):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
01-21 23:26:47.304: E/AndroidRuntime(1456):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
01-21 23:26:47.304: E/AndroidRuntime(1456):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
01-21 23:26:47.304: E/AndroidRuntime(1456):     ... 11 more
01-21 23:26:47.304: E/AndroidRuntime(1456): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment cannot be cast to android.app.Fragment
01-21 23:26:47.304: E/AndroidRuntime(1456):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:585)
01-21 23:26:47.304: E/AndroidRuntime(1456):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:560)
01-21 23:26:47.304: E/AndroidRuntime(1456):     at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4709)
01-21 23:26:47.304: E/AndroidRuntime(1456):     at    android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680)


 <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="17"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
<permission
    android:name="com.geekdev.animalpark.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
 <uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />
 <uses-permission android:name="com.geekdev.animalpark.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

        <!-- Goolge Maps API Key -->
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="AIzaSyCSzy5IWRWvMUn8xt5I17Z-1l7xtzYM0Js" />
```

i have tried everything that i found on the internet but nothings work here please tell me the appropriate solution for this please please

Comment: Doesn't the maps api use the support library? If so, you need to use getSupportFragmentManager() and use support.Fragment instead of the built in Fragment class.

Comment: Where is the solutions please tell me

Comment: @CommonsWare the link you send didnt work

Comment: are you using Android Studio or Eclipse?

Comment: @natez0r didnt worked

Comment: @ZohraKhan android studio

Comment: "the link you send didnt work" -- the link is to another StackOverflow question, and the link definitely works. You may need to try another browser, if the browser you are using is unreliable.

Comment: @CommonsWarei mean its solution

Answer (score 0):

Meta data should be part of application tag

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="AIzaSyCSzy5IWRWvMUn8xt5I17Z-1l7xtzYM0Js" />
```

EDIT:

```
    <application>
    <activity
                ...
    ..
    ..
            </activity>
      <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="Yourkey" />
</application>
```

Comment: class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"  Delete this line. you minSDKVersion is 17

Comment: is it right to enter ? 

<!-- Goolge Maps API Key -->
 <meta-data
     android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.AIzaSyCSzy5IWRWvMUn8xt5I17Z-1l7xtzYM0Js"
     android:value="AIzaSyCSzy5IWRWvMUn8xt5I17Z-1l7xtzYM0Js" />

Comment: In android:value paste your key AIzaSyCSzy5IWRWvMUn8xt5I17Z-1l7xtzYM0Js and make sure that you generated the key with the same package name.

Comment: @ user3193538 Any Progress?

Comment: nope still the same issue

Comment: Please paste your manifest & XML code again. Delete the old xml code from question.